# XNA model's transparent textures are white Blender 2.8

Tags: transparency

I have no idea how to fix this problem, this is what I get every time I try to render with Cycles. I use Blender 2.8. I also added a picture of the nodes, if that helps.

Rendered:

---

[image]

Node setup:

---

[image]

Comment: Most likely the alpha channel for that image is not fully black for those strands of hair.

Comment: How would I change that? I'm pretty new to Blender 2.8, so forgive me if my knowledge on it is not that great.